# What is the property of the eigenvalues of this matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

$A+A^{\dagger} = I$

What is the property of the eigenvalues of this matrix?
I think they should be real and $A$ is hermitian. But I cannot prove this.

Comment: Thanks. But the left part is a sum. I cannot separate $A$ out of the sum.

Comment: @xavierm02 Not sure what you mean: $A+A^\dagger$ is already diagonal.

Comment: @xavierm02 $I$ is diagonal.  Are you perhaps suggesting that $A$ and $A^\dagger$ are simultaneously unitarily diagonalizable?

Comment: $A^*A=(I-A)A=A(I-A)=AA^*$ so $A$ is normal and you can diagonalize it.

Answer (score 1):

By the given condition, we see that $A=\frac12I+K$ for some skew-Hermitian matrix $K$. Since skew-Hermitian matrices have purely imaginary eigenvalues, it follows that the real part of every eigenvalue of $A$ is $\frac12$.

The eigenvalues can be non-real. E.g. consider $A=\frac12\pmatrix{1&-1\\ 1&1}$. Its eigenvalues are $\frac1{\sqrt{2}}e^{\pm i\pi/4}$.

Comment: Is $A$ normal in this case?

Comment: @Elessarr Why didn't you verify it by yourself? Yes, it's a scalar multiple of a rotation matrix, hence normal.